# C++ KMP algorithm printing output in main

Tags: c++, algorithm

I got interested with text algorithms, I did find some ready example of C++ implementation of Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm which unfortunately does not include any working main() function. 
I'm total newbie, hence it's hard for me to write any main function which will allow me to show the output of the code written below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> KMP(string S, string K)
{
    vector<int> T(K.size() + 1, -1);
    vector<int> matches;

    if(K.size() == 0)
    {
        matches.push_back(0);
        return matches;
    }
for(int i = 1; i <= K.size(); i++)
{
    int pos = T[i - 1];
    while(pos != -1 && K[pos] != K[i - 1]) pos = T[pos];
    T[i] = pos + 1;
}

int sp = 0;
int kp = 0;
while(sp < S.size())
{
    while(kp != -1 && (kp == K.size() || K[kp] != S[sp])) kp = T[kp];
    kp++;
    sp++;
    if(kp == K.size()) matches.push_back(sp - K.size());
}

return matches;
}
```

As I understand, this function uses vector type to store all positions which match text with given pattern. -> vector 
it returns vector type and I would like to print the results.

I'm supposed to take two inputs from user string S and string K, to be able to use KMP function which uses S&K strings as its arguments.

Than I guess it would be useful to somehow print out the results of function (what this function KMP returns), but as it turned out simple cout command didn't do the trick.

Should I use some kind of an iterator to display results returned by KMP function or what ? 
Forgive me my novice level, but I can't figure it out all by myself.

```
int main()
{
  string A,B; 
  cout << "Input the text&pattern in the following order: text first, pattern second";

  cin >> A; 
  cin >> B; 

  KMP(A,B); // initialize function with given strings  ?

  //using iterator to display the results; 

 for(vector<int>::iterator it = matches.begin(); it != matches.end(); it++) 
 {
    cout << *it << endl; 
 }

 return 0; 
 }
```

Comment: Pass strings by const reference.

Comment: That's a nice KMP algorithm you have there, and I'm going to let you finish, but I just have to say, Boyer-Moore is the best string search algorithm of all time.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<int> matches = KMP(A,B);
```

You need to catch the returned vector from function and store its value in a vector (that you call matches).

Note that this `matches` is different from the function local variable `matches`.

Comment: Ok, copy that. I did try to print out vector<int> matches after adding this line to main() function, but plainly it didn't work. I got the idea of what you've meant and I fully understand the whole logic but still can't figure out how to print the results which have been 'caught' by vector initialized in main() function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another variable to hold the value, which is a `vector<int>`, return by the function.

To obtain the value, you should use a variable with **the same type as the return type of the function**:

```
vector<int> returnValue = KMP(A, B);
```

To print out the value, you should do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < returnValue.size(); i ++)
{
    cout << returnValue[i] << endl;
}
```

Therefore, your `main` may look like this:

```
int main()
{
    string A,B; 
    cout << "Input the text&pattern in the following order: text first, pattern second";

    cin >> A; 
    cin >> B; 

    vector<int> returnValue = KMP(A, B); // do KMP match and store the result in returnValue

    // print out the values 
    for (int i = 0; i < returnValue.size(); i ++)
    {
        cout << returnValue[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0; 
 }
```

Comment: you're welcome :) don't forge to mark it as answer :D